# Widevine Content Decryption Module for Chromium

Tags: windows, html, chromium, codec, widevine

I want to [enable Widevine Content Decryption Module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190762/chromium-enabling-widevine-content-decryption-module) on [Chromium](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crupdater/) (v51) under Windows (64b) to play HTML5 video content.
Is it [possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172364/netflix-works-on-chrome-but-not-chromium) on windows ? Or are there any [alternatives](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chromium-widevine/) ?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,

**Download the extension**

the address is `https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/*$LATEST*-win-x64.zip, where *$LATEST* is the contents of this file https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/current.txt i.e.:
https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/1.4.9.1088-win-x64.zip

**To install**

- unzip the downloaded file
- go to chromium extentions, enable developer mode
- then click the "Load Unpacked" button
- browse to and select the folder you unzipped the download to.

worked this out thanks to these instructions for linux:
https://andreafortuna.org/2019/09/24/how-to-install-latest-widevine-plugin-on-chromium/

> On Google servers, the latest version number is available on the url
> https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/current.txt so, with a simple
> script we can automatically download the most recent version:
>
> #!/bin/bash LATEST=`curl https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/current.txt` wget
> https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/$LATEST-linux-x64.zip

> Websites to test Widevine:
>
> https://demo.castlabs.com/ (Choose videos with labeled “DRM”)
>
> https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/
>
> https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm